# HTML/JS: How can you upload a file if you're not allowed to have its full path?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an "select file" button which opens a file dialog to select a file to upload. I get the file name (but not the full path) and save it onto the adjacent input.

Now I have an upload button and I'd like to upload the file to my PHP backend without having to reload my entire page. But -- how do you know where to take the file from if you're only given the filename, but not the full local path?

Comment: The browser knows it, it just doesn't expose it to you. It does, however, expose a File object to you -https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/File

Comment: You wouldn't do anything with the real local path anyway because for obvious reasons web sites aren't allowed to just pull files from the user's computer based on file name and path.

Comment: _"have an "select file" button which opens a file dialog to select a file to upload."_ , _"have an upload button and I'd like to start an AJAX upload to my backend"_Start upload within same handler as file selection ? Can include `html` , `js` at Question ? Or, save `File` object to variable to be used at submit

Comment: [Layer of Abstractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_layer). Details are hidden from you, in this case, it's because of privacy and security.

Comment: Ideally I want to use one button to choose a file, and another, once a file has been chosen, to start uploading it via ajax OR ANY other method WITHOUT having to re-load my entire page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the [`files` property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_fileupload_files.asp).

Let's suppose you have the following `input type=file` into a form in your HTML code:

```
<input type="file" id="upload" />
```

Then you'll use it like:

```
(function(d) {
  d.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    var files = d.getElementById('upload').files;
    if (files.length > 0) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var formData = new FormData();
      for (var i = 0, ii = files.length; i < ii; i++)
        formData.append("file" + i, files[i]);
      xhr.open('POST', url); // change the url variable to some URL you're using
      xhr.send(formData);
    }
  });
})(document);
```

---

PS: Note that the `files` property works in all the evergreen browsers (Chrome, Opera, Firefox, Safari etc) and IE10+. It doesn't work in older IE versions, and there is no other way to upload files via AJAX.

---

**EDIT**

After reading your comment:

> Ideally I want to use one button to choose a file, and another, once a file has been chosen, to start uploading it via ajax OR ANY other method WITHOUT having to re-load my entire page.

You can do exactly what I said above, but in a different way, e.g:

```
<input type="file" id="myfile" />
<button id="upload">Upload</button>
```

And then:

```
(function(d) {
  d.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var files = d.getElementById('myfile').files;
    if (files.length > 0) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var formData = new FormData();
      for (var i = 0, ii = files.length; i < ii; i++)
        formData.append("file" + i, files[i]);
      xhr.open('POST', url); // change the url variable to some URL you're using
      xhr.send(formData);
    }
  });
})(document);
```

---

And if you need to support IE9 or below, you won't be able to do the upload via xhr, and you will need to target your `form` to an invisible `iframe`, and then it won't reload your entire page. E.g:

```
<form target="other" action="url"><!-- change the url to what you're using -->
  <input type="file" id="upload" />
  <iframe name="other" style="display: none"></iframe>
</form>
```

Comment: do I have to submit and reload my entire page? can't I have t javascript function that simply starts where the "var file =..." begins and uses XMLHttpRequest to upload the files without having to submit anything?

Comment: You can put `e.preventDefault()` in the first line of the `submit` event, so it won't reload the entire page. You can also don't use the event `submit` at all. You can send the `xhr` in the `input type=file` `change` event, if you prefer. Or you can put a `button` upload and send the xhr there. It's up to you to choose where to use the `var files (...)` wherever you want to.

Comment: @RM1970 I've edited my answer to explain your needs better.